# Android getDimension returns wrong value for textSize

Tags: android, android-resources, dimensions

I am setting the textSize this way:

`textView.textSize = view.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.body_h3_text_size)`

Here is how my dimension is defined in XML

`<dimen name="body_h3_text_size">16sp</dimen>`

When I open the app, the text is super large. And while debugging `view.resources.getDimension` returns 44 instead of 16

Comment: Because its in `Pixel` . Check the method definition in comments you will find `Resource dimension value multiplied by the appropriate metric to convert to pixels`.

Comment: Ok. But how to get this 16sp value?